# Git: Patching changes made in an unrelated repo

Tags: git, merge, diff, patch

Let me explain the problem with a example:

Suppose I commit several changes to files located in the `OldRepo/libs/graphics` directory in my project's git repository.

Now, I begin working on a new project with a new version of graphics

`NewRepo/Dir1/libs/graphics`

I want to apply all the changes made to the graphics directory in the old project repository to the graphics directory in the new project repository
(please notice `Dir1` in the path of the new repository).

I am looking for a solution which transfers the changes and the individual commits from the `OldRepo` to the `NewRepo` so tools like `git diff` and `diff` are not sufficient.

How can I accomplish this?

**The actual problem I am trying to solve is as follows**

I started an iphone project with `cocos2d-iphone` version 1.1. 
It's from xcode template; it creates a brand new project with new repo with initial commit containing `cocos2d-iphone` version 1.1 (Note: it's just source).

I continue to develop my project... commit, commit... *[Added new files]*
At some point, I need to alter the behavior of cocos2d-iphone version 1.1 so I directly change the source code and commit my changes..*[Improved Cocos2d-ccnode]*.  and.. *[Improved Cocos2d-ccsprite]*

And finally I release the app.

Now, I am starting a new project and `cocos2d-iphone` version 2.0 is available.
I installed new project template (with `cocos2d-iphone` version 2.0).

Created new project from template; once again it's a brand new project with a new repo with initial commit containing `cocos2d-iphone` version 2.0

Note that `cocos2d-iphone` version 2.0 is not an entire rewrite of 1.1 but contains small changes.

I would like to apply the improvements I made to `cocos2d-iphone` version 1.1 to my new project. Definitely not in a single commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
  cocos1.1        cocos2.0 (you work on this right now)
    \        
     \    
    changes
```

that's what you have, right? So what you want is pick the exact changes you made on cocos1.1 and apply it to cocos2.0? my suggestion is to `git cherry-pick`your changes.

You can rebase as well, but I am not sure it will work, since cocos2.0 seems not to be directly linked to cocos1.1 (you can try this way as well though)

By the way, I suppose cocos1.1 and 2.0 are not the same local repo. so you should add cocos1.1 as a remote first : in cocos2.0, run `git remote add cocos1.1 path/to/cocos1.1`. Then `git branch --track cocos1.1changes cocos1.1/desiredbranch`.

So you figure your list of commits, say c1 to c20 (you will need to use their SHA-1 hash). They are on `cocos1.1changes`branch.

what you will do is `git checkout cocos2.0` to work on the right branch, and then apply your commits. You can start by doing simply `git cherry-pick c1` (c1 being the SHA-1 hash)

I think there are tricks like `git cherry-pick c1~c20`or something like that, but anyway get some info about cherry-picking, I think that's what you need.

Good luck

Comment: I am creating old repo with a publicly available copy of graphics lib.

Comment: Let me clarify once again: I created the old project with a publicly available copy of graphics lib. When I completed old project; new graphics lib is available and I should create the new project with the new graphics lib; but I made lot private changes (improvement!) to old graphics lib and I want to bring back those changes.

Comment: so you want to rebase? your changes and the new graphics are both "children" commits of the old repo? In this case what you should do is something like `git rebase` or simply a merge (you can keep the history of your changes by merging into your local copy). If that's it I'll edit the answer

Comment: New graphics not a children (In git perspective), however its built on old graphics, so many files are same as old one with few modification. (Actually: the graphics library is nothing but cocos2d-iphone.) When I want create a new project I am creating it from xcode template so git relationship between old and new library break.

Comment: May be I am misleading you with my question. I just edited my question to elaborate it.

Comment: check out the edit, at the end of the answer. Let me know if it sounds correct.

Comment: Ok cherry-picking for worked me. I selected individual SHA and cherry-picked manually. It worked. But I am not happy with it. Anyway thanks for you time and patience.